# How to replace/change specific words of a textbox with other text field input

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop

my question is that I've a windows form with two text fields. One text field is hidden and other is visible and the hidden one has text "ABCDEFG"and what i want to achieve is that when a user inputs like "Hello" in the visible text field then click a button and then the hidden text field should change its text as well like "ABCDHelloG" in which only specific letters from the middle change into the user input. Is that possible in C# ? If you are thinking why would someone even do that, then i would say, its for triggering and exporting a file from resources. And if you may ask why i need to do that, then, its for a project, I'm bound to work within these conditions.

Comment: What is the rule that explains the replace for the letter EF and not something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the hidden text as a format string.

```
string template = "ABCD{0}G"; // {0} is the placeholder for user value
string initial = string.Format(template, "EF"); // initial value of hidden field
// initial == "ABCDEFG"
```

Then insert your value using string format:

```
string userValue = "Hello";
string result = string.Format(template, userValue);
// result == "ABCDHelloG"
```

You have to make sure that the template is not overwritten if this has to work multiple times in a row.